Rails Upgrade 5.2 -> 6.0: NoMethodError: undefined method `configs_for'
I'm working on upgrading a large rails app from 5.2 -> 6.0. All specs are passing, and the app runs fine. However, running bundle exec rails db:migrate is causing errors.  I've been able to run the pending migrations via rails console, but struggling to figure out what's wrong. I suspect its related to this change  and a dependency, but nothing in the stacktrace is pointing me in the right direction.
Any insight would be much appreciated?
root@22c16ca6386d:/app# bundle exec rake db:migrate
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:66: warning: already initialized constant Net::ProtocRetryError
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:68: warning: previous definition of ProtocRetryError was here
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:206: warning: already initialized constant Net::BufferedIO::BUFSIZE
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:214: warning: previous definition of BUFSIZE was here
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/protocol.rb:503: warning: already initialized constant Net::NetPrivate::Socket
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/net-protocol-0.2.2/lib/net/protocol.rb:541: warning: previous definition of Socket was here
[IdentityCache] Missing CAS support in cache backend ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoizedDalliStore which is needed for cache consistency
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `configs_for' for #<Hash:0x0000556d02525ed0>
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/hash_dot-2.5.0/lib/hash.rb:19:in `method_missing'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/activerecord-6.0.6.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:84:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/rake-13.2.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/gems/bundler-1.17.3/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/home/circleci/.rubygems/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


The error seems to be coming from the hash_dot gem which (for very good reason) has never been included in Rails. You can use gem dependency -r hash_dot to see what gems you have that have snuck it in.
